# print attribute of object with jsp expression in jsp file

Tags: java, jsp

i send the object to jsp with set.Atrribute and i want to print this object in h5 tag with jsp exprissoin but i can't. my cod is:

```
<% 

                     List<News>news = (List<News>) request.getAttribute("news");
                     for(int i=0;i<news.size();i++){
                         News n = news.get(i);  

                    %>
                     <div class="card text-white bg-info mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
                        <div class="card-header">gggggggggggggggggg</div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title"> <% n.title %> </h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <%
                     }
                    %>
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "can't".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the title member of News then it should work as is

if you use encapsulation and you expose the title field the you have to call the get method which is public.

```
<h5 class="card-title"> <% n.getTitle(); %> </h5>
```

if it does not work try this and make sure you follow this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm):

```
<c:forEach items="${(List<News>) request.getAttribute("news")}" var="news">
    <div class="card text-white bg-info mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header">gggggggggggggggggg</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">${news.title}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

also, in order for the c tag to work you have to declare the tag library:

```
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
```

Comment: title is public in definition but n.title don't work

Comment: when i use n.title in first part of expression on below for statement is work but in h5 tag is not work